# DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'BroadcastChannel': Request object could not be cloned

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Using Redux-Toolkit with Redux-Persist and Redux-State-Sync. The error occurs on every page load and state change only if I use `createStateSyncMiddleware`.

Here is the store file:

```js
const persistConfig = {
  key: "test",
  debug: true,
  storage: createIdbStorage({ name: "Store", storeName: "test" }),
  whitelist: ["cachedData"],
  version: 1
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  global: globalReducer,
  component: componentSlice,
  cachedData: cachedDataSlice,
  [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).
      concat(createStateSyncMiddleware({ blacklist: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER] }), apiSlice.middleware, rtkQueryErrorLogger),
});

initMessageListener(store);
```

Comment: From what I can tell from these Github issues (*[issue#49](https://github.com/aohua/redux-state-sync/issues/49), [issue#53](https://github.com/aohua/redux-state-sync/issues/53)*) this error appears related to passing non-JSON serializable action payloads, e.g. like what Redux-Persist uses. But I see you've already included the appropriate actions in the blacklist. I wonder if you've some other atypical Redux action payloads. FWIW RTK already includes Thunk middleware, so adding `thunk` is completely unnecessary. See if adding the `createStateSyncMiddleware` first helps.

Comment: @DrewReese updated the code according to your comment. but still error exist

Comment: It may be difficult, but do you think you could try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that reproduces the error that we could inspect live?